# Convert json file with multiple lines to R dataframe

Tags: r, json, dataframe, rjson

I'm using `jsonr` to read a JSON file in to R. However, the `fromJSON(file="file.json")` command is only reading the first line of the file. Here's the JSON:

```
{"id":"a","emailAddress":"a@a.com","name":"abc"}
{"id":"b","emailAddress":"b@b.com","name":"def"}
{"id":"c","emailAddress":"c@c.com","name":"ghi"}
```

How do I get all 3 rows into an R dataframe? Note that the above content lives in a single file.

Comment: Is that a correctly defined json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a hacky way to do that; First i read in the whole file/string with readr, then i split the data by new lines "\n", and finally i parse each line with fromJSON and then i bind it into one dataframe:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(readr)

json_raw   <- readr::read_file("file.json")
json_lines <- unlist(strsplit(json_raw, "\\n"))
json_df    <- do.call(rbind, lapply(json_lines, 
                                  FUN = function(x){as.data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(x))}))
```